# Make active slide slightly bigger on Smart Slider Carousel

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

I'm pretty new to the coding world, so please be patient with me. I'm working on a slider to show testimonials and the design calls for the middler slider to be slightly bigger and positioned higher than the others, but am having trouble understanding how to target it.

I'm using the wordpress plugin Smart Slider 3 and believe I could use an animation to do this, but not sure how and which animation to use or if I need to add some css to make it work. 
Does anyone know which animation setting could help, otherwise I will work on targeting the active slide in style.css.
Thank you in advance if anyone is able to help!

[Currently how slider looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyfVl.jpg)

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wMaT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a specific animation to do what you want. You have a "size" tab, there you can make a fixed slide. With fixed I mean you can set it a bit higher and the sizing is up to you too.
Also if you could post an image or something would be helpful.